# LDAP authentication with Jetty

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jetty, jaas

I am trying to setup a LDAP based authentication with Jaas on Jetty.

I've first configured `Jetty->Jass` trying with a property file login module, then when this done i am changing to Ldap based login module ... but i have a weird problem:

I have this configuration

```
jettyLogin {
   org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
    debug="true"
    contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    hostname="localhost"
    port="1389"
    bindDn="uid=admin,ou=People,o=acme,dc=example,dc=com"
    bindPassword="admin"
    authenticationMethod="simple"
    forceBindingLogin="false"
    userBaseDn="ou=People,o=acme,dc=example,dc=com"
    userRdnAttribute="uid"
    userIdAttribute="uid"
    userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
    userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
    roleBaseDn="ou=Roles,o=acme,dc=example,dc=com"
    roleNameAttribute="cn"
    roleMemberAttribute="member"
    roleObjectClass="groupOfNames";
   };
```

for a LDAP entry like this

```
dn: uid=jduke,ou=People,o=acme,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: person
uid: jduke
cn: Java
sn: Duke
userPassword: theduke
mail: jduke@acme.example.com
```

What i see is that `LdapLoginModule` is called and searchs for the user; the user is found but when attributes are retrieves userPassword attribute is missing (!!) ... then it stays null and authentication fails.

I cannot understand why `userPassword` attribute is not retrieved.

Comment: Few LDAP implementations will return a userPassword values and they should not. You should NEVER expect to receive a value for userPAssword. The user should provide the password and the application should bind as the user.

Comment: mmm ... maybe i am wrong but as i see it the action of authenticate a user is not done by LDAP server ... so the server should provide the password in any way to allow that to be compared with the one provided by the user ... this, the action of authenticate is performed by the login module. The code of the Ldap login module looks very clear in that way. It is expecting to locate a userPassword attribute retrieved by the LDAP.

Comment: I am not familiar with the login module, but few LDAP implementations will return a userPassword values and they should not.

Answer (score 4):

The login module should not try to retrieve the userPassword attribute. LDAP is an authentication protocol and has its own method for doing so called a bind.

The JAAS module for Jetty will try to perform a bind using the supplied credentials if you configure it correctly. If you change

```
forceBindingLogin="false"
```

to

```
forceBindingLogin="true"
```

in your configuration then it should work for you.